# I'm cooking a Romanian meatball soup for 60 people. How much of this soup do I need to feed 60 people?

Tags: meat, storage-method, stock, bulk-cooking

This is the [recipe](https://savoriurbane.com/ciorba-de-perisoare-reteta-mamei-mele/) (in Romanian) for the meatball soup.

Here is the ingredient list translated:

- Servings: a pot of 5 L
- Ingredients - savoriurbane.com
- 2 carrots
- 1 parsley root
- 1 root parsnips
- 1 celery root (medium)
- 2 tablespoons of oil
- 1 onion
- 2 potatoes
- 500 ml broth of tomatoes (of the house) or the tomato paste to the box (mashed) or 3-4 fresh tomatoes (summer)
- approx. 500 g vegetables of your choice: pod of beans, peas, florets of cauliflower, diced turnip, etc.
- 1 small bunch of thyme dry

For the meatballs:

- 500 g minced pork (or mix with beef)
- 50 g rice (about 2 tablespoons)
- 1 small onion chopped
- 1 tablespoon of oil
- salt, freshly ground pepper
- 1 teaspoon of sweet paprika (paprika)
- 1 teaspoon dry thyme, chopped
- 1 egg white raw

In addition:

- sour cream tart for dres soup
- 1 raw egg yolk
- lemon juice, vinegar, bors or dies
- a handful of greenery (leaves of parsley and dill)
- optional: chopped leaves of lovage

Additional translations re the amount of water and the total amount of soup the recipe makes:

> I added the rest of the roots and I dropped everything with 4 L of hot water.
>
> From the ingredients below we obtained a soup pot of approx. 5 L.

Comment: I'm not sure how much you'd want to serve each diner, but calculating 250ml, this 5l recipe serves 20 people. You'd have to multiply by three to serve 60.

Comment: If, instead of a cup, your serving size is a bowl, that's 375ml, this recipe serves 13.33 people. You'd have to multiply by 4.5 to serve 60. You would need 22.6l of soup.

Comment: The recipe says to use a 5 liter pot, not that it makes 5L of soup. It is not going to make anywhere close to the soup shown in the pictires if diluted  close to 5L

Comment: @Cynetta, is that Italian? I don't speak Italian.

Comment: The serving size would be in a bowl..considering the amount of vegetables and meatballs I need to add extra water to the 22.6l .Thank you both :)

Comment: @DumitruSzabolcsMihai Could you edit your question to include the amount in liters your original recipe gives, and I'll edit an answer for you to accept. Oh, and welcome to this Q&A site.

Comment: @BaffledCook - No, Google Translate says it is Romanian

Comment: The linked recipe should make 5L. See my answer below.

Answer (score 6):

After looking at many very similar recipes (in English) for Romanian sour meatball soup, or Ciorba de Perisoare, I'm inclined to think that this recipe does indeed make 5 liters.

Most all of the recipes I've looked at start with 500g of meat and have pretty much the same ingredient list. This [recipe found on  CookingGlory](http://www.cookingglory.com/recipes/meal-ideas/soups-stews/meatball-sour-soup/) says to :

> Add about 12 to 16 cups of water (about 4l).

Based on this, I find it easy to believe that the finished soup would easily be 5 liters. (Also, in the translation provided by another user, it shows an amount of 5 liters.)

Also, translated from the link provided in the question:

> From the ingredients below we obtained a soup pot of approx. 5 L. You can reheat without problems and it is tastier every day (kept in the refrigerator lasts for 3-5 days).

And:

> I added the rest of the roots and I dropped everything with 4 L of hot water.

The recipe on Cooking Glory states that it makes 8 - 10 servings.

So, basic math in hand, 5 L of soup, multiplied by 6 = 30 L of soup. That would give you sixty 500 ml portions.

The link above to the Cooking Glory page also gives a lot of information about the soup and its ingredients.

Answer (score 2):

This is Google Traslate's version of the recipe plus my answer. Google Translate says it is in Romanian

Only 500g of pork plus mass of the rest of the ingredients for the raw meatballs. I estimate the total mass of the raw meatballs to be about 710g
Assume the raw mass of each meatball to be about 35g. You will be able to make about 20 meatballs.
Decide how many meatballs per serving? One pic shows 5 another shows 3. The recipe will serve between 4 and 7 portions.
Divide into 60 portions and you will need to multiply the recipe between 9 and 15 times to arrive a a decent answer.

---

Mousse soup - my mother's recipe

Portions: a pot of 5 L
Ingredients - savoryurbane.com

```
2 carrots
1 roast parsley
1 pasta root
1 root celery (medium)
2 tablespoons of oil
1 onion
2 potatoes
500 ml tomato sauce (tomato sauce) or tomato paste in box (pasato) or 3-4 fresh tomatoes (summer)
approx. 500 g of choice vegetables: bean paste, peas, cauliflower, cubes, etc.
1 bunch of dry thyme
```

For perry:

```
500 g pork minced (or mixed with beef)
50 g rice (about 2 tablespoons)
1 small chopped onion
1 tablespoon of oil
salt, freshly ground pepper
1 teaspoon sweet potato (paprika)
1 teaspoon dried thyme, chopped
1 raw crust
```

In addition:

```
sour cream for sour soup
1 raw yolk
lemon juice, vinegar, bors or dies
a handful of green (parsley and dill leaves)
optional: chopped leaves of leustean
```

Comment: I'd err on the 'big eater' side. 5 servings, so you have to multiply by 12 to have a decent amount for 60 people.

Comment: @BaffledCook especially as such soups in Europe are seen as apetisers and served in pretty small bowls or cups.

Comment: I don't disagree with the calculations re the meatballs but it seems like you would need to know the total amount this recipe makes, accounting for all ingredients, and the desired serving size to give an accurate answer. Also, I'm not seeing any amount of stock or water. Surely there must be some added.

Comment: Does Google reall give you mousse soup instead of meatballl soup? And Perry instead of meatballl?  fascinating. Now I don't wonder why we have questions on charcoal dressing.

Comment: @Johannes_B Googe Translate - https://translate.google.com/